# INSERT SQL statement with button click event issue

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I feel like I'm missing something minor. This `btnSave_Click` event handler should update my database - what am I missing? I'm not getting any error message.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
        sqlconn.Open();

        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand();
        String sqlquery = "INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (EDIPI) VALUES(@EDIPI)"; 
        sqlcomm.CommandText = sqlquery;
        sqlcomm.Connection = sqlconn;

        sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@EDIPI", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 5).Value = txtEDIPI.Text;

        sqlconn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error is " + exp.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure the Method gets executed? Also are you using any Framework for interfacing with the Database?

Comment: I think you are missing an execute. and look into "using keyword" in c# for db connections `using(SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn))`

Comment: Execute your query: `sqlquery.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add:

```
sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just need to add sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery(); Thank you everyone! and user2042214 for the answer just with a extra period.